# Why is my rebinding of Caps Lock reversed?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I use this snippet in my Emacs startup file:

```
(if (eq window-system 'x)
    (shell-command "xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 66 = F13'"))
```

to rebind Caps Lock. However sometimes the binding suddenly doesn't work anymore as if I had turned it off myself. But I have no idea what key sequence I could have used. After evaluating the code block manually it works again.

So my question is what could cause this sudden reversal of my binding ?

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and the Emacs version is GNU Emacs 25.1. I use a USB keyboard.

Comment: This could happen because key bindings are lost when a keyboard is unplugged. Are you using an internal keyboard or a USB one? Might the loss of the binding coincide with a system upgrade?

Comment: USB keyboard. And no, there was no upgrade running. However it doesn't happen really often. Maybe once in a week. I can't really say how often.

Comment: I think it only happens during long term emacs sessions.